# What exactly are you supposed to test when doing TDD

Tags: php, android, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I have read several articles for about 2 months about TDD and I have a vague idea of what am I testing. The first that comes to my mind is testing the output: for example, using `PHP` as a web scripting language, I test my `JSON` output so that the response from the server is:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Chris",
    "token":"5ke3k62$5%34^%k3"
}
```

So if the response matches the previous JSON string, the test passes. I'm not 100% sure this is what TDD is all about, but that's what I understood.

So what about lets say a mobile app. I want to make a **hello world** app. An `Activity` with a `TextView` that displays "Hello world".  What would be a test case, and what am I supposed to test. Please give me small examples so I can understand what it is all about.

Answer (score 1):

TDD is not a style of testing, but a style of development. To employ TDD:

1. Test exactly one thing you wish your app already did
2. Run the test to be sure it fails (to prevent a false positive, later)
3. Write as little code as possible until you've made the test pass
4. Rinse and repeat

If you're not sure how to write a test, for step 1, refer to the documentation of your favourite test framework.

Comment: Ok, let's suppose I want to have an `Activity` with a populated `ListView`.  The listview data will be loaded from an string-array resource. What would my test(s) contain, etc.  please explain this example to understand

Comment: I'm not sure what framework/DSL you're using, but here's an abstract example:

Comment: `test: list_should_populate_from_sa_resource\n Make SA_Resource["A", "B", "C"] -> the_resource\nMake Activity[the_resource] -> A\n Expect A.list_view to match the_resource\n :end_test`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Not sure what I did wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Test what you expect the code to do.  If you expect the code to output that json, then write a test to check that.  Be descriptive about what you expect the code to do e.g.

```
Should_return_json_response
Should_return_name
Should_provide_a_token
```

You're saying what you want the code to do before you write it.  How you achieve that in the code is then up to you, as long as you get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

TDD refers to the practice of writing unit tests.  Unit tests are tests focus on testing small units of code. Generally you would want to test the state changes made by calls to public methods on a class. The tests should cover all code paths within that method. If your unit test relies on a dependency that crosses a boundary e.g. makes a call out to a database, email, the file system, from a web client to server the test is no longer a pure unit test. It now becomes an integration test.

I have written a blog post that covers how you would do test first TDD to build your code under test. You can read the post [here](http://chilliandrew.blogspot.com/2013/12/tdd-so-whats-this-test-first-thing.html). I know the code isn't PHP, but the concepts are the same. [Here](http://www.codersdojo.org/statistics/54b228b2cfaebc7136db438432c60e6b7ee1bef3) is the kata done in php.